# How to open new window in one click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, click

I have a function that opens a new window when clicked on button. When I first click, nothing happens, but when I click a second time, the window opens. My code:

**Script**

```
  <script src="<c:url value="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('click','#add',function(){
    $( ".editField").click(function() {
      var clickedValue = $(this).find('td:first').text();
      window.open('/somePage' + clickedValue, 'New window');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML body**

```
<table>
<tr><td>th text</td></tr>
<tr class="editField">
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td colspan="2">
            <input id = "add" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Never put an event handler inside another event handler

Comment: The event handler of <tr> is only added, when you click inside of you document, hence two clicks. Change that to $(document).ready(function() { $(".editField").click(function() { ... } ));

Comment: @adeneo care to expand?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has two event listeners, one for `$(document).click` and another for your `.editField`.

The problem is, you've put them inside one another, so the `.editField` listener isn't added until the document has been clicked, hence the need for two clicks.

```
$(document).on('click','#add',function(){ // << first click
  $( ".editField").click(function() {     // << event listener added, second click
    /*...*/
  });
});
```

You only need one listener:

```
$( ".editField").click(function() {
  var clickedValue = $(this).find('td:first').text();
  window.open('/somePage' + clickedValue, 'New window');
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by clicking on a button you've binded click on tr.editfield, but not window opening.
So if you then click on a tr (any place, including button) - you will get new window opening.
If you want just open new window on a button click, use this code:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add").click(function() {
 var clickedValue = $(this).parents('.editField');
 clickedValue = $('td:first', clickedValue).text();
 window.open('/somePage' + clickedValue, 'New window');
 return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Final solve:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".editField #add").click(function() {
      var clickedValue = $(this).parents('.editField');
      clickedValue = $('td:first', clickedValue).text();
      window.open('/somePage' + clickedValue, 'New window');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```